# Php and oracle OCI query

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface, oci8

I have a prolem with this code

```
$stmt = oci_parse($db, $sql);
$isQueryOk = oci_execute($stmt);
if ($isQueryOk) {
    while (($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt)) != false) {
        array_push($results, $row);
    }
    echo json_encode($results);
} else {
    $msg = "Error FETCHING ALL [$sql] on " . mb_strtoupper($dbTable) . "!";
}
```

The problem is that if `oci_fetch_assoc($stmt)` return 20000 rows, the `while (($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt)) != false) {
        array_push($results, $row);
    }`
takes to much time. Is there a way that i can return `echo json_encode($results);` without the WHILE cycle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use oci_fetch_all: http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php

Comment: i've tried but cannot format as key=>value pair. Returns ex:    {EMPRESA: ["CLCA", "CMIP", "CPP"], VAL: ["CLCA", "CMIP", "CPP"]} and i need   [{EMPRESA: "CLCA", VAL: "CLCA"}, {EMPRESA: "CMIP", VAL: "CMIP"}, {EMPRESA: "CPP", VAL: "CPP"}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OR try to use another way to push your array. "Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function." http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

```
$results[] = $row;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it'll be significantly faster, but as [Marcos Sedrez wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107363/php-and-oracle-oci-query#comment67486568_40107363) you can try using `oci_fetch_all`. You'll need to pass it a flag to return by row (instead of by column, the default) to match your current output format:

```
oci_fetch_all($stmt, $output, 0, -1, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);
json_encode($output);
```

See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php) for further information.

Answer (score -1):

The error message is not output anywhere, so if there was an error it won't be visible

try this one

```
$stmt = oci_parse($db, $sql);
if ($stmt === false) {
    $error = oci_error($db);
    $msg = "Error PARSING [$sql] on {$dbTable}: {$error['message']}";
} else {
    $isQueryOk = oci_execute($stmt);
    if ($isQueryOk) {
        $results = array();
        while (($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt)) !== false) {
            array_push($results, $row);
        }
        echo json_encode($results);
    } else {
        $error = oci_error($stmt);
        $msg = "Error EXECUTING [$sql] on {$dbTable}: {$error['message']}";
    }
}

if (isset($msg)) {
    error_log($msg);
    http_response_code(500);
    echo 'Internal Server Error';
}
```